# Does SendMail Support TLS Certificates With Subject Alternative Names?

Tags: smtp, email-server, sendmail, tls

CentOS 5.x

Does SendMail support TLS certificates with Subject Alternative Names?

I have a set of sendmail servers and would like to use the same certificate for all of them (to save time and recurring expenses).  Will this work?

Comment: Why are you using such an OLD version of Centos?  I'd seriously consider upgrading to take advantage of patch upgrades for stability and security and possibly enhanced performance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the support for subject alternative names is primarily a client side issue. There the SAN entries have to be checked when the request hostname doesn't match the Common Name in the certificate.

Sendmail simply loads and presents the certificate and doesn't even need to interpret the SAN entries encoded in there, I think.

But even if some server side support is required, that would come from the OpenSSL library, which has support for X509 V3 extensions (including Subject Alternative Names) since OpenSSL 0.9.2. RHEL 5 ships with 0.9.8 IIRC

I would even hazard a guess that most SMTP servers simply use the SSL for transport security and by default don't do any verification if the certificate common (or Subject alternative) name matches the hostname and simply use the provided public certificate regardless.